# Right way of citing: First author and year the same, co-authors differ

Tags: biblatex, author-number

We had a short [discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197510/31323) about distinguishing bibliography, if the first author and the year is the same, but the co-authors differ. M

Now I'm facing a similiar "problem" by myself or rather do not understand the behavior of `biblatex`. This questions is more about the right way of academic citing and less a matter of LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Smith:2004,
   author = {Smith, Andrew and Sparks, Leigh},
   title = {All About Eve?},
   journal = {Journal of Marketing Management},
   volume = {20},
   number = {3-4},
   pages = {363--385},
   year = {2004},
}

@article{SmithEtAl:2004,
   author = {Smith, Andrew and Sparks, Leigh and Hart, Susan and Tzokas, Nikos},
   title = {Delivering customer loyalty schemes in retailing: exploring the employee dimension},
   journal = {International Journal of Retail \& Distribution Management},
   volume = {32},
   number = {4},
   pages = {190--204},
   year = {2004},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 

\begin{document}         

\textcite{Smith:2004} as well as \textcite{SmithEtAl:2004}\ldots  
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The result is

> Smith and Sparks (2004) as well as Smith, Sparks, et al. (2004)...

but why? The second entry could be Smith et al. (2004) and it would be clearly distinguishable from the first entry. Why is the second author named?

Comment: the same behavior seems to apply if the first paper is only by one author (e.g. Smith (2004)) and a second of the same lead author together with others gives Smith, Sparks, et al. (2004) - even though in this case with the 'et al.' they would be completely unambiguous.

Comment: If the first paper were only by "Smith", you would get "Smith et al." for the second paper. It is just a convenient extra that `biblatex` lets you easily see that both papers were written by "Smith and Sparks" in your example. Indeed, it is possible (if not entirely correct if you're a stickler for Latin grammar) that the first citation is compressed to "Smith et al."; in that case one would not want both citations to read "Smith et al.". If you really care only about best practice in citing though, you are better off asking this at [academia.SX](https://academia.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I agree with you, @moewe, as stated [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197498/for-2-references-the-full-author-list-is-displayed-for-all-other-references-on/197510#comment458153_197510). I see the point, that both "Smith et al." doesn't make any sense. However my question was, why it is Smith, *Sparks*, et al. (2004) in the second citation? In this case a "Smith et al." would be enough to dinstiguish it from "Smith and Sparks". But taking your comment, I guess my answer is "it's not a bug, it's a feature" ;) Thanks!

Comment: You can disable this behaviour with `uniquelist=false`. Have a look at p. 60, p. 187 and pp. 234-236 §4.11.4.2 *Lists of Names (`uniquelist`)* in the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just summarising my earlier comments, so we have an answer here.

If the first paper were only by "Smith", you would get "Smith et al." for the second paper. It is just a convenient extra that biblatex lets you easily see that both papers were written by "Smith and Sparks" in your example.

Indeed, it is possible (if not entirely correct if you're a stickler for Latin grammar - though you only get into trouble if the abbreviation is expanded) that the first citation is compressed to "Smith et al."; in that case one would not want both citations to read "Smith et al.".

Furthermore, it would seem quite arbitrary which of the two combinations is allowed to be "Smith et al.", so it is better to not let either have it.

Indeed, the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) has a similar example in §4.11.4.2 *Lists of Names (uniquelist)*, pp. 234-236.

> Consider the following data:
>
> - Doe/Jones/Smith 2005
> - Smith/Johnson/Doe 2005
> - Smith/Doe/Edwards 2005
> - Smith/Doe/Jones 2005
>
> In order to disambiguate author lists, you are usually required to add more names, exceeding the `maxnames`/`minnames` truncation point. The `uniquelist` feature addresses
>   this requirement. With `uniquelist=true`, we would get:
>
> - Doe et al. 2005
> - Smith, Johnson et al. 2005
> - Smith, Doe and Edwards 2005
> - Smith, Doe and Jones 2005

Strictly speaking here "Smith, Johnson et al." could be "Smith et al.", but then one could ask why it is not one of the "Smith, Doe and ..." that got to be "Smith et al.".

You need to keep in mind that these citations are there to help you find the work in the bibliography list at the end of the document.
Suppose I were only to read one chapter of your book where you cite only "Smith, Sparks, et al." which comes out as "Smith et al.", and I find both the entries for "Smith and Sparks" and "Smith, Sparks, et al." in the bibliography with all names printed, I would have to think quite hard to tell which is which.

That all said, you can disable this feature with `uniqelist=false` and then get

- Smith and Sparks (2004)
- Smith et al. (2004)